# Date.toString not showing local timezone

Tags: java, date, calendar, locale

I have a webapp . I am trying to log the time at which certain process got completed.

```
m_jobResults.addMessage("sum done", new    Date().toString());
```

I am seeing that `Date.toString()` returns time in GMT as opposed to local timezone . If I write a test java  program on same machine , it displays time in my local timezone. Could anyone suggest what is going wrong here.
Also note `java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone()` shows gmt while debugging in webapp where as a sample test code shows as correct local timezone .

Answer (score 1):

First you have to know is:

- [`Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is *always* UTC-based.
- Date does not have a "local instance."

If you want to have a to have a *local* time zone, use `Date` with [`Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and/or [`TimeZone.getDefault()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()).

Use `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid")` to get the Barcelona time zone.

If you want to find your server timezone [check here](http://hanuska.blogspot.com.es/2008/08/how-to-get-servers-timezone.html):

```
final TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
```

But maybe your server is not located where your user is... so to **get user's locale** with your server's timezone:

```
private String getServerTimeZoneDisplayName()
{
    final TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    final boolean daylight = timeZone.inDaylightTime(new Date());
    final Locale locale = servletRequest.getLocale();
    return timeZone.getDisplayName(daylight, TimeZone.LONG, locale);
}
```

Comment: How do I find timezone of my server? java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone()  is returning me only  gmt.

Comment: @jetty If that returns GMT, then the default timezone of your server is set to GMT.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert a `Date` to a `String` directly, as you are doing by calling `toString()` on it, it will be formatted with the default timezone of the system that the code is running on. This happens to be GMT in your case.

If you want it to be formatted using a different timezone, then use a `SimpleDateFormat` object and specify the timezone you want on that object:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));

String text = df.format(new Date());
System.out.println("The date and time: " + text);
```

Comment: That's the issue. My system(server) is in IST . I also tried the toString() after changing my regional settings to Australia and setting timezone to Adelaide. My code is running  else where from GMT and yet toString is displaying time in GMT.

Comment: is there a way to find where default timezone is getting picked up from. As it is different for my jdk and webapp server jvm.?